# Document set workflow not allow to add document inside it when Workflow is in In-progress State?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

[image][image]I have one document set name as "DocSet" and i have sharepoint 2013 workflow on it it is started on item added so when user add any document it will check whether it's content type is "Document Set" then assign task to some user otherwise Workflow completed.

But when workflow is in-progress then any user come and upload document inside that document set then it give error that document already modified by that user. I have also have some metadata columns so upload document also update metadata.

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of the workflow?

Comment: Please check above screenshot